# How can I estimate a user's physical location?

Tags: javascript, web, geolocation, geocoding

I would like to know the ways in which I could estimate a user's physical location without having to request geolocation permissions on their browser. For example sites like cragslist, and gmail can estimate my location however I never granted them geolocation permissions through my browser.

So how are they doing this? through my IP? which service "translates" the IP to a physical location estimate? and can this be done exclusively on the client side?

Comment: It can be difficult for the client itself to know its outward facing IP address, so you usually use a server-side service to resolve the geolocation by request IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ipinfo.io/ has a very nice and free api for getting estimated locations from IP address.

Comment: While this is certainly what I was thinking of, the sites I mentioned have more fine tuned precision to where they can estimate to my neighborhood so far the two services here have only been able to detect my city.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's as good as it gets without requesting geolocation permissions.

Comment: @naughtyboy One way google estimates location is: if you are in your house and any device in the house has given their GPS to Google, Google now associates that precise geolocation with that IP address. If future people don't give them exact GPS, Google can just query their mappings of IP address to location.

Answer (score 1):

The ip address  - there are plenty of services that you can submit the ip and get back the location, and even if it's a proxy ip or a real one.

Of-course it's not GPS based, and can eaily tricked using vpn.

here is one [free geo ip](https://freegeoip.net)